# How to return latest Mysql entry through JQuery/Ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pull the latest entry of a mysql table through ajax and display it as html content inside a div. I have ajax and php functioning correctly, the only problem I have is that I want to query for new entries and stack the results at a time interval within a loop and I've run into two problems: getting the data to behave like a normal javascript string, and getting the loop to only return unique entries.

update.php file

```
$con=mysqli_connect("mydbhost.com","username","password","database_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM conversations");
$j = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$carray[j] =   $row['comment'];
$j++;
}
$comment = (array_pop($carray));
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

JQuery Ajax request loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var comment;
  function commentLoop() {
    comment = $('#testdiv').load('update.php');
    $('#testdiv').append(comment);
    setTimeout(commentLoop, 6000);
  }
  commentLoop();

  $(document).focus();
});
```

Comment: As a previous answer has stated, your SQL returns everything in the table, but then you loop through all the data and only return the last row in your echo.  Also, you are using `$_POST['comment']`, but nothing is being posted to the script.  On top of that, in your AJAX, you load the page in to the div... and then append the result of that load (it's a non returning function) to the same div.  So really, there are quite a few things that could be going wrong for you here.

Comment: I removed the $_POST('comment'). It has nothing to do with my error.

Comment: You are still selecting everything in the table and only sending one of those back to the AJAX call.  If need be, use sessions or another method so you know where you left off last time it was loaded and then include that in the select statement so you select the correct amount of rows that you actually want to deal with and output them all for your AJAX.  Also, you are still replacing the entire DIV every time you run `commentLoop()`.

Comment: @jon The loop works with just a regular string. what makes setting the js comment variable to an echoed php string different? http://jsfiddle.net/CaJ2D/

Comment: Look at the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, it puts the contents in to the div, replacing it.  Saving the variable `comment` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Jon you're guidance basically solved my problem for me. Its a shame you never posted a solution so I could accept it.

Comment: Haha, wasn't sure anything I said was worth putting in to an answer, but rather the discussion itself. ^^  I'm glad I was able to help you solve the problem though ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will count the comments in the table and select the last entered comment then pass them to ajax as `json` data only if the received count is lower than the count of the comments in the table:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['data']))
{   
    $con        = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
    $init_count = $_GET['data'];
    $stmt1      = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM conversations";
    $stmt2      = "SELECT comment FROM conversations ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT 1";

    $total = $con->prepare($stmt1);
    $total->execute();
    $total->bind_result($count);
    $total->fetch();
    $total->close();    

    if( ($init_count != '') && ($init_count < $count) )
    {
        $lastComment = $con->prepare($stmt2);
        $lastComment->execute();
        $result = $lastComment->get_result();
        $row    = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $lastComment->close();

        $data = array(
                 'comment' => $row['comment'],
                 'count'   => $count
                 );
    }

    elseif($init_count == '')
    {
        $data = array(
        'comment' => '',
        'count'   => $count
        );
    }
    $pdo->close();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="count" value="" />
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    function getComment(){
        var count = $('#test').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'update.php?data=' + count,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
            {
            $('#count').val(data.count);
            if(data.comment) !=  $('#testdiv').html(data.comment);
            }
        });
    }
    getComment();
    setInterval(getComment, 6000);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is by doing `SELECT * FROM conversations` you keep requesting whole table -- although you only take the last one.

Your code need to remember which comment has been loaded, and only get any comment newer than that.

For example, assuming your primary key is incremental, do `SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE convid > ?`. Replace `?` with latest comment that has been loaded. If you're loading for the first time, just do `SELECT * FROM conversations`

You could pass the last comment id displayed using request parameter into `update.php`. Also I recomment returning the data in JSON format so you can return a collection of comment and id and parse it easily

Comment: Not really true, he's only gather the last one (look at the `array_pop` method used after the while loop).  Also, he's replacing the entire DIV every time he calls the `load` function.

Comment: my $comment variable only stores the last element in an array which is storing all the comments in order of entries.

Comment: @Emanegux Yes, but there is no need to populate a full array of comments to then only use one of them and discard the rest, you should only select the last one if you only want the last one.

Comment: @Emanegux ah sorry I missed that array_pop bit, but yes selecting the whole conversations table isn't very efficient

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM conversations order by insert_date desc limit 10
```

insert_date  the date time comment is inserted, i hope you will have a field for storing that if not add it now