# Jquery to display name from dynamic selected option

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to display selected display name from selected values. The values display here is dynamically and it works when i use alert But I am very confusing to set a seperate text as selected values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(function() {
         $('#select').change(function(){ 
          showval=$(this).val();
             alert(showval); 
             $('#' + showval).show();
         });
       });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $base_url;?>user/insertleaveappln">
      <div class="modal-body p-b-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Leave Type</label>
                    <select name="leavetype" class="form-control" id="select">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>  
                          <?php foreach($leavetype as $leaveappln_info){ ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $leaveappln_info->leavetype_id?>"><?php echo $leaveappln_info->leavetype_name; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>  
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>   

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    <label class="form-control-label">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="start_date" class="form-control startdate" placeholder="Start Date" id="startdate" required onchange="cal()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    <label class="form-control-label">End Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="end_date" class="form-control enddate" placeholder="End Date" id="enddate" required onchange="cal()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    <label class="form-control-label">Count Days</label>
                    <input type="text" name="count_days" class="form-control" placeholder="Count Days" id="countdays" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    <label class="form-control-label">Reason</label>
                    <textarea name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason"> </textarea> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Suppose that if i want select first option as one it displays another div as you are selected one and if i select option as two it displays you are selectd two like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        $('#select').change(function(){ 
   showval=$(this).val();
            $('#hiddenval').val(showval);
   $('.show_selected').html("Your selected name:"+$(this).find('option:selected').text());           
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form method="POST" action="localhost/user/insertleaveappln">
        <div class="modal-body p-b-0">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div>
                    <label class="form-control-label">Leave Type</label>
                      <select name="leavetype" class="form-control" id="select">
                          <option value="select">Select</option>  
                            <option value="1">1 name</option>
                            <option value="3">3 name</option>
                            <option value="2">2 name</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>   
              
              <div class="show_selected"></div>
              <input type="hidden" name="display_name_id" value="" id="hiddenval">
              
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div>
                      <label class="form-control-label">Start Date</label>
                      <input type="date" name="start_date" class="form-control startdate" placeholder="Start Date" id="startdate" required onchange="cal()">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div>
                      <label class="form-control-label">End Date</label>
                      <input type="date" name="end_date" class="form-control enddate" placeholder="End Date" id="enddate" required onchange="cal()">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div>
                      <label class="form-control-label">Count Days</label>
                      <input type="text" name="count_days" class="form-control" placeholder="Count Days" id="countdays" readonly>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div>
                      <label class="form-control-label">Reason</label>
                      <textarea name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason"> </textarea> 
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> 
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Select option is display so the value could be as 1,2,3,....like that but i want display the actual name instead of id and also display as div text not in textbox like if i choose name 1 it display the text as "you select name" show remaining selected values are hide id I choose name 2, name 2 only show name 1 will hide like that

Comment: Cheers @sixthstar

Comment: I want to display a mysql count inside jquery using an ajax. Will you able to help me sir @Hariharan

Comment: Try to refer this else post as a new question, many are here to help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15918137/5276354